# HTML - <p> Tag no newlines

Tags: html, tags

Ok, I have a `<p>tag</p>`, but it's not creating newlines when I add them. For example, this:

```
<p>Hello, this is simply a test. For some reason when I add a new line by pressing enter
like this, it won't save.</p>
```

prints as:

```
Hello this is simply a test. For some reason when I add a new line by pressing enter like this, it won't save.
```

If you look here http://sesau.ca/ksp/KMP.html, and view source, you can see that he just uses paragraphs and he gets newlines by an enter. He does not use br or anything.

Comment: Yeah, because newlines don't mean anything in HTML. Should be one of the first things any HTML tutorial/book explains.

Comment: I don't see where "he's using `<p>`s and gets newlines."

Comment: Question: Where do you think the line breaks on this very Stackoverflow page here are coming from in the text *you* typed here?

Comment: Since this comes up basically as the first result, you can use `white-space` for a css tag and probably get what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

To add newlines, insert the respective `<br>` tags:

```
<p>Hello, this is simply a test. For some reason when I add a new line by pressing enter
<br>
like this, it won't save.</p>
```

HTML parsers basically condense whitespaces to a single space (exception are `<pre>` tags and `white-space: pre` CSS). So your inserted linebreaks are basically being ignored. If you want a linebreak, you have to explicitly insert it by using the `<br>` tag or use the aforementioned alternate `<pre>` tags or `white-space` css property.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do that. Shouldn't my actual new lines translate to newlines on the webpage without using <br>? Look at my link, he just uses <p>'s and he has new lines..

Comment: @Syd Whitespaces are more or less ignored by the parsers at many points. If you want a linebreak, tell the parser by using `<br>`.

Comment: Look at my link.. he just uses a paragraph and no br's, and he gets new lines..

Comment: I see no explicit linebreaks within you example. All seem to be added implicitly.

Comment: You can see his text doesn't run to the edge of the page..

Comment: @Syd Because the page has *margins*! It has nothing to do with manually added newlines.

Comment: You know, that the browser will break lines, if they do not fit the current box? You do not have to specify those. If you resize your browser window, the line breaks will change. The author at no point can specify linebreaks for all those sizes.

Comment: @deceze How do I add margins? Also, what is the point of a <p> if you can just use <br>?

Comment: @Syd The point of using `<p>` (as well as any other element) is to group content, e.g., to style it in a common way.

Comment: @Syd https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started

Comment: `white-space: pre-line` is also ok for IE. :)

Answer (score 1):

Html consider newlines only in `<PRE>` tag.
To have newline in `<P>` tag use `<BR/>` tag instead of enter.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_paragraphs.asp

Comment: Obligatory: http://w3fools.com

Comment: Yes, but the guy in my link doesn't do that.. he just uses a <p> and he gets new lines..

Answer (score 0):

Technically, `<br>` and `<br />` both work, but you should use `<br />` for XHTML compliance, [as you can read here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.6)